# Register Redis with Simple Injector

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, redis

I have an older ASP.NET WebForms application in which we are using Simple Injector as our DI Container. I would like to find an equivalent to what is below. Below uses the **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection** in a Startup.cs of a .NET Core application to register **Redis**. Is there a way to do this with Simple Injector? Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConn");
            options.InstanceName = "MyApplication_";
        });
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [this integration page](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/servicecollectionintegration.html). Although it talks about console applications, you'll find it applicable to situations where you need to integrate 3rd-party library components into Simple Injector that require MS.DI for their integration.